# Xcode 4: Add Build Carbon Resources Build Phase

Tags: xcode

I've just migrated to Xcode 4 and I need to add "Build Carbon Resources" build phase to my project. It appears Ok (and does what it should) when I open old prjs (from Xcode 3), however I can't add it to a new prj, the menu "Add Build Carbon Resources Build Phase" is disabled. How can I enable it?

Thanks